# Number of combinations of balls in slots

Tags: combinations, hash-function

Assume there are 9 identical balls, and each can be placed in one of 10 numbered slots.  All balls must be placed in exactly one slot (i.e., you can't leave a ball out).  How many combinations are possible?

To explain a little better, I want to create a "hash" function for Social Security Numbers (SSNs).  The hash will end up being a 10-digit number, where each digit is represented by the number of times that digit is found in an SSN.  Each of the "balls" in the original question represents a digit from the SSN, while the slots represent a number from 0 (in the low-order position) through 9 (in the high-order position).

For example, an SSN of 123-45-6789 would result in a hash of 1111111110, since the digit "0" (zero) never appears, but each of the remaining digits appears once.  Another example:  111-22-3333 would result in a hash of 0000004230, since "3" appears 4 times, "2" appears twice, and "1" appears 3 times.

I'm trying to determine the selectivity of my hash algorithm.  Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm understanding your problem correctly we can reinterpret it as trying to find the number of integer solutions to $x_0 + x_1 + \dots + x_9=9$, where $x_i \ge 0$. Each of the $x_i$ stands for the number of times digit $i$ shows up in the SSN, and the sum of 9 shows that each SSN has 9 digits.

We can use a variant of the stars and bars counting method (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)#Theorem_two) to see that we need to calculate the binomial coefficient $\binom{18}{9}$, which gives us the answer of 48620 different solutions.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I was looking for...  Thanks very much!